# SQL to SQL data export Vs copying Database files

Tags: sql-server

I have data on a MS SQL Server in the US and i want to copy it to SQL servers in London.

What would be a quicker way to do this, using the export option and export the data to the SQL Server in London using SQL export & Import wizard, or detach and copy the database file and attach it in the destination server.

The file size is around 36 GB.

Comment: As there are so many different factors that could affect the speed that tend to be both network- and database-specific, the easiest approach may be to try with significantly smaller data files first.

Comment: It would be simpler to just back the file up to a _compressed_ backup file and restore it on the other side. You can be fairly certinan a compressed backup will be smaller than 36Gb.